# Install meteor server in debian (lenny)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian-lenny, meteor

I wonder how can I install [this](http://meteorserver.org/installation/) in a lenny machine. Well, [this site](http://meteorserver.org/installation/) has instructions on how to do this, but in step 3 I can't do `cd /usr/local/meteor` because this folder doesn't exist! How I can connect meteor server with apache2 and php? **I don't know what version of Perl I have installed but when I type perl into the bash, doesn't output command doesn't exist.. Any help, would be useful.

I want to add meteor as a tag to my question but, the system doesn't allow me. An administrator can fix it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instruction on the meteor site suggests using `/usr/local/meteor` as the installation directory, means you have to manually create it first (!).

```
mkdir /usr/local/meteor
```

After that you switch into it the newly created directory (`cd /usr/local/meteor`) AND AFTER that you continue the step by step instructions starting with `wget ....`

To "connect" apache2/php with meteor you have to run `mod_proxy` and reverse proxy meteor. Search for `mod_proxy` on how to do this. serverfault.com should provide you with the required information about mod_proxy.